# SWT: How to get the default (preferred) size of a Control

Tags: java, controls, swt

An SWT component only has a `getSize()` method. It returns the actual size of this control. But how to get the default size of a component, especially if a different one already has been set before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain the default size by calling `computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT)` on your widget. You may pass a default height or width instead of `SWT.DEFAULT` in cases such as a multiline Label, where you'd want to know its natural height given a maximum line width, for instance.

For all standard widgets, `computeSize` disregard the value passed in any previous `setSize` calls.